# How do I do what strtok() does in C, in Python?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and trying to figure out an efficient way to tokenize a string of numbers separated by commas into a list. Well formed cases work as I expect, but less well formed cases not so much.

If I have this:

```
A = '1,2,3,4'
B = [int(x) for x in A.split(',')]

B results in [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

which is what I expect, but if the string is something more like

```
A = '1,,2,3,4,'
```

if I'm using the same list comprehension expression for B as above, I get an exception. I think I understand why (because some of the "x" string values are not integers), but I'm thinking that there would be a way to parse this still quite elegantly such that tokenization of the string a works a bit more directly like ***strtok(A,",\n\t")*** would have done when called iteratively in C.

To be clear what I am asking; I am looking for an elegant/efficient/typical way in Python to have all of the following example cases of strings:

```
A='1,,2,3,\n,4,\n'
A='1,2,3,4'
A=',1,2,3,4,\t\n'
A='\n\t,1,2,3,,4\n'
```

return with the same list of:

```
B=[1,2,3,4]
```

via some sort of compact expression.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about this:

```
A = '1, 2,,3,4  '
B = [int(x) for x in A.split(',') if x.strip()]
```

x.strip() trims whitespace from the string, which will make it empty if the string is all whitespace. An empty string is "false" in a boolean context, so it's filtered by the if part of the list comprehension.

Comment: strip() is overkill here, converting to int already takes care of the whitespace... better filter out the invalid substrings.

Comment: strip() is necessary, or you will get a ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '   '

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, I will answer this seven year old question:
The C program that uses strtok:

```
int main()
{
    char myLine[]="This is;a-line,with pieces";
    char *p;
    for(p=strtok(myLine, " ;-,"); p != NULL; p=strtok(NULL, " ;-,"))
    {
        printf("piece=%s\n", p);
    }
}
```

can be accomplished in python with re.split as:

```
import re
myLine="This is;a-line,with pieces"
for p in re.split("[ ;\-,]",myLine):
    print("piece="+p)
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally, I try to avoid regular expressions, but if you want to split on a bunch of different things, they work.  Try this:

```
import re
result = [int(x) for x in filter(None, re.split('[,\n,\t]', A))]
```

Answer (score 4):

Mmm, functional goodness (with a bit of generator expression thrown in):

```
a = "1,2,,3,4,"
print map(int, filter(None, (i.strip() for i in a.split(','))))
```

For full functional joy:

```
import string
a = "1,2,,3,4,"
print map(int, filter(None, map(string.strip, a.split(','))))
```

Comment: `print map(int, filter(len, map(str.strip, a.split(','))))` Note: str.strip(i) and i.strip() are the same (no need in `string` module). `len` is used for readability.

Comment: I prefer `string.strip()` as it safely deals with Unicode strings.

Comment: @Alec: `map(type(a).strip, a.split(','))` will work both for Unicode and encoded strings.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, and never raise an exception, if all the numbers are ints. The `isdigit()` call is false if there's a decimal point in the string.

```
>>> nums = ['1,,2,3,\n,4\n', '1,2,3,4', ',1,2,3,4,\t\n', '\n\t,1,2,3,,4\n']
>>> for n in nums:
...     [ int(i.strip()) for i in n if i.strip() and i.strip().isdigit() ]
... 
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: The isdigit check is not necessary for the test cases provided, but it does add extra robustness.

Comment: The first i.strip() is redundant.

Comment: You're performing i.strip() three times per element.  Yikes.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
>>> a = "1,2,,3,4,"
>>> map(int,filter(None,a.split(",")))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

filter will remove all false values (i.e. empty strings), which are then mapped to int.

EDIT: Just tested this against the above posted versions, and it seems to be significantly faster, 15% or so compared to the strip() one and more than twice as fast as the isdigit() one

Comment: he needs it to filter whitespace

Comment: Yes, this will filter out whitespace: >>> int(" 1 ") ==> 
1

Comment: This fails if any of the empty entries has whitespace, e.g. '\n\t,1,2,3,,4\n'

Answer (score 1):

Why accept inferior substitutes that cannot segfault your interpreter? With ctypes you can just call the real thing! :-)

```
# strtok in Python
from ctypes import c_char_p, cdll

try: libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
except WindowsError:
     libc = cdll.LoadLibrary('msvcrt.dll')

libc.strtok.restype = c_char_p
dat = c_char_p("1,,2,3,4")
sep = c_char_p(",\n\t")
result = [libc.strtok(dat, sep)] + list(iter(lambda: libc.strtok(None, sep), None))
print(result)
```

Comment: added `cdll.LoadLibrary('msvcrt.dll')`

Comment: When I saw the `while` loop I'd thought of `lambda tokenize dat, sep: itertools.chain((strtok(dat, sep),), iter(lambda: strtok(None, sep), None))`. It is funny how similar programmers' minds work. Add the smile emoticon back otherwise somebody can think that the code is not a joke.

Answer (score 1):

I am a novice to Python but you can try this.

```
>>> x = "123---  456,,, 789"
>>> y = [int(j) for j in (x.translate({ord(i):' ' for i in "- ,"}).split())]
>>> print (y)
[123, 456, 789]
```

The portion `x.translate({ord(i):' ' for i in "- ,"}).split()` can emulate `strtok(x, "- ,")`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap in a try except block which catches anything not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

I was desperately in need of strtok equivalent in Python. So I developed a simple one by my own

```
def strtok(val,delim):
    token_list=[]
    token_list.append(val)  
    for key in delim:       
        nList=[]        
        for token in token_list:            
            subTokens = [ x for x in token.split(key) if x.strip()]
            nList= nList + subTokens            
        token_list = nList  
    return token_list
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess regular expressions are the way to go: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html