# How can I do strtok()-type parsing in Python?

Tags: python, strtok

The title of [How do I do what strtok() does in C, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456084/how-do-i-do-what-strtok-does-in-c-in-python) suggests it should answer my question but the specific strtok() behavior I'm looking for is breaking on any *one* of the characters in the delimiter string.  That is, given:

```
const char* delim = ", ";
str1 = "123,456";
str2 = "234 567";
str3 = "345, 678";
```

strtok() finds the substrings of digits regardless of how many characters from delim are present.  Python's split expects the entire delimiting string to be there so I can't do:

```
delim = ', '
"123,456".split(delim)
```

because it doesn't find delim as a substring and returns a list of single element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that the tokens are going to be numbers, you should be able to use the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) function from Python's [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module:

```
import re
re.split("\D+", "123,456")
```

More generally, you could match on any of the delimiter characters:

```
re.split("[ ,]", "123,456")
```

or:

```
re.split("[" + delim + "]", "123,456")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `replace()` to normalize your delimiters all to the same character, and `split()`-ting on that character, is one way to deal with simpler cases. For your examples, `replace(',',' ').split()` should work (converting the commas to spaces, then using the special no-argument form of `split` to split on runs of whitespace).

In Python, when things start getting too complex for `split` and `replace` you generally turn to the `re` module; see Sam Mussmann's more general answer.

Comment: This isn't really an answer right now. Maybe give an example of using re for this purpose.

Comment: This also wouldn't work for the provided `str2`, where the numbers are delimited by space characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
def strtok(mystr,delim):
    nlist=[]
    nelem=""
    
    for c in mystr:
        if c in delim:
            if nelem!="":
                nlist.append(nelem)
                nelem=""
            nlist.append(c)
        else:
            nelem+=c
            
    if nelem!="":
        nlist.append(nelem)
            
    return nlist
    
print(strtok("wow - noway. - can't be.",".-' "))
print(strtok("123,456",", "))
```

Comment: If you don't want the delimiters in the list then drop the line "nlist.append(c)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).